# Issue when adding user control in data grid using wpf programatically

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have created user control and adding to data grid using code behind . For user control i have created 2 constructor to pass the data for showing .

> User control constructor:

```
public OverlayControlView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
}

public OverlayControlView(string value, List<Function> functionList)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OverlayValue = value;
            OverlayMenuItem = functionList;
}
```

> Adding user control to data grid:

```
var overlayControlView = new OverlayControlView(caption, functionList);
                        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(overlayControlView.GetType());
                        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DependencyObject));
                        dataTemplate.VisualTree = factory;
                        dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
                        dataGrid.Columns.Add(dataGridTemplateColumn);
```

Problem is after adding user control to grid , its always calling parameter less constructor and the value inside user control become empty. It call parameter constructor first when i am adding user control programmatically then it automatically calling parameter less constructor.

How to solve this issue!

Comment: Obviously your `overlayControlView` isn't used at all by the CellTemplate. This is just how it works. Drop the constructor with parameters and set the two properties by appropriate Bindings.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the point , can you please help me with example of how we can set properties by binding and not by constructor.

Comment: Declare the CellTemplate in XAML and write something `<local:OverlayControlView OverlayValue="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}" .../>`. There are many examples on the internet.